# Obtener balance total de Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe

tengo integrada en un proyecto Laravel la pasarela de pagos de Stripe con Cashier, necesito poder obtener el balance total de pagos (ingresos) de mi cuenta de stripe.
He estado consultando la Api y no encuentro un método para ello.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la API de Balances, eg.:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance \
  -u sk_test_1234:
{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "amount": 87102563,
      "currency": "usd",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 87102563
      }
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "mxn",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "usd",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "mxn",
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hay bindings de PHP también:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_123");
\Stripe\Balance::retrieve()
```

aunque no sé exactamente como se integra con Cashier

Comment: Si en 'amoun' viene la cantidad por ejemplo: 1451, ¿como se si es 14,51€ o 145,1 € ?

Comment: @MarioAzcúnagaVeiga depende de la moneda; si es basada en decimales o enteros. Más información acá: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal